Warning: keyslot operation could fail as it requires more than available memory. | How to decrypt LUKS drive on Raspberry Pi?
I am attempting to decrypt a LUKS drive on a Raspberry Pi 2B but am having immense issue preventing the machine from freezing.
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda4 drive
Enter passphrase for /dev/sda4:
Warning: keyslot operation could fail as it requires more than available memory.

Can I set the program to run slower or perhaps utilize a different tool for LUKS? I need to be able to read some data on it.
Thank you so much for any help.

Is your question different to this: Open: cryptsetup out of memory ("Not enough available memory to open a keyslot.").

@PhilipCouling Thank you so much for your response. I have no idea how I missed this one. Kind of? This question helps provide some information as to why this may be an issue but it does not provide a solution.

However, it may just be that there is no solution and I cannot under any circumstance open this specific drive on the Raspberry Pi.

Set a lower memory limit for your argon2 keyslots or use pbkdf2 keyslot which has no memory cost at all. The linked question should have some suggestions. (If  the current keyslots requires more memory than your Raspberry can make available, you might be stuck and have to do this on another system). Also cryptsetup luksDump should show your keyslot types and memory costs.

@frostschutz I believe the solutions provided were to create a new LUKS drive. I have data on this drive I need to access.
